# vscode内でSELECT文出力したところ、１日ずれてしまう

Tags: vscode, postgresql

現在SQLの学習をしているのですが、VScodeのpostgreSQLだとDATE型が登録したデータと表示されているデータが異なって表示されてしまっています。
pgAdminでは正常に表示されたのでVScode内の問題だとは思うのですが何分初心者なので詳しくわかりません。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

追記: https://github.com/Borvik/vscode-postgres/issues/219
は確認済み
CURRENT_DATE,CURRENT_TIME,CURRENT_TIMESTAMPの結果(2023/06/14 16:34)
[image: CURRENT_DATE,CURRENT_TIME,CURRENT_TIMESTAMPの結果]

実行環境
Windows11
VSCode 1.79.1
postgre 15.3
pgAdmin4 7.1

追記:VSCode拡張機能一覧
・Auto Rename Tag(https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.auto-rename-tag)
・Community Material Theme(https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Equinusocio.vsc-community-material-theme)
・Extension Pack for Java(https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-java-pack)
・Debugger for Java(https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-java-debug)
・Language Support for Java(TM) by Red Hat(https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-java-pack)
・Test Runner for Java(https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-java-test)
・Maven for Java(https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-maven)
・Project Manager for Java(https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-java-dependency)
・IntelliCode(https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioExptTeam.vscodeintellicode)
・indent-rainbow(https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=oderwat.indent-rainbow)
・Indenticator(https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SirTori.indenticator)
・apanese Language Pack for Visual Studio Code(https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MS-CEINTL.vscode-language-pack-ja)
・Jupyter(https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-toolsai.jupyter)
・Jupyter Cell Tags(https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-toolsai.vscode-jupyter-cell-tags)
・Jupyter Keymap(https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-toolsai.jupyter-keymap)
・Jupyter Notebook Renderers(https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-toolsai.jupyter-renderers)
・Jupyter Slide Show(https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-toolsai.vscode-jupyter-slideshow)
・markdownlint(https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DavidAnson.vscode-markdownlint)
・Material Icon Theme(https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=PKief.material-icon-theme)
・Material Theme(https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Equinusocio.vsc-material-theme)
・Material Theme Icons(https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Equinusocio.vsc-material-theme-icons)
・Output Colorizer(https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=IBM.output-colorizer)
・PostgreSQL(https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ckolkman.vscode-postgres)
・Prettier - Code formatter(https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode)
・Pylance(https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.vscode-pylance)
・Python(https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python)
・vscode-icons(https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscode-icons-team.vscode-icons)
・

Comment: VSCode の拡張機能を使用しているなら、こちらの Issue に該当しそうです。 [Columns of type Date are displayed as one day off](https://github.com/Borvik/vscode-postgres/issues/219)

Comment: 質問に答えていただきありがとうございます。しかし、ここから治し方がわからないためどうすればいいのかわかりません。

Comment: インストールされている拡張機能は https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ckolkman.vscode-postgres ということで正しいでしょうか？　VS Code 上で PostgreSQL にクエリできる拡張機能は複数あるので確認です。

Comment: はい、その拡張機能です。拡張機能も追記しておきます。